# How to display Web site in Android WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

I am new to Android `WebView`, in my application i need to display a web site conatins 3 web pages. In the first web page there will be a link to navigate to the second page and second to third page. I given the URL in the `WebView`, the first page is displayed perfectly, when i click the link it directly opens the browser application to display the second page. But i want to display the second page in the `WebView` itself. Please find my code below:

```
  WebView forumView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.forumView);
  forumView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
  forumView.loadUrl("url");
```

As i said i am very new to `WebView` my code might be wrong, please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in Advance,
Rajapandian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to intercept the clicks yourself if you don't want the default Android behavior.

You can monitor events in a `WebView` using a `WebViewClient`. The method you want is `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`. This allows you to perform your own action when a particular URL is selected.

You set the `WebViewClient` of your `WebView` using the `setWebViewClient(`) method.

If you look at the WebView sample in the SDK there's an example which does just what you want. It's as simple as:

```
private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This piece of code will help you.

```
wbb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView_tobe_loaded);

    WebSettings wbset=wbb.getSettings();
    wbset.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wbb.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    String url="http://www.google.com";

    System.out.println(getdeviceid());
    wbb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wbb.loadUrl(url);
```